# Find company names in a dataframe containing news from each row of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, text, nlp

I have a list of company names stored in a dataframe which was created from an imported file

```
comp_names <- data.frame((contacts[,6]))
```

[image]

Now I would like to search for those names in another dataframe in which in each row there is different news. This dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Of course the above is a simplified example. I would like to check comp_names by scanning through the text contained in each row of the other dataframe.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

I have tried a few things but none seem to work.
The final output should be a logical vector. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Please do not share pictures of data, rather provide it via `dput()` so that we can easily copy and paste it on our end.

Comment: "The final output should be a logical vector" A vector for each company? Or just a vector if any company is mentioned?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It should be a logical vector if any company is mentioned. I'm trying with grep, but I'd appreciate any other suggestions. Thank you

Comment: Again, please provide the output of `dput()` of both data sets in order to help instead of screenshots. I'm not going to type these out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.